# eslint: How to disable certain "eslint-disable-" syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

In a project we our working on we use fairly strict eslint rules for good reason. Occasionally we need to break one of the rules, so we would disable a rule for a specific line. For example:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-console
```

In this case we use the `eslint-disable-line` syntax with the specific rule that we want disabled, to avoid accidentally disabling other rules that are important.

Occasionally a dev will sneak a file in that has `// eslint-disable-line` without the specific rule, or the dreaded `/* eslint-disable */` at the file level.

What I am looking for is a way to force eslint to only accept directives when they include one or more specific rules, so that, for example

```
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
```

would still disable that specific check, but

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

without the rule would still result in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin [eslint-plugin-eslint-comments](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments) is what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31939705)

Comment: If you think the answer is not complete, then anyone can improve it on this, and add anohter answer(And, directly point to the source of the answer is fit for some users).

The plugin author provides the most accurate answer, and the paraphrase will make noise. Besides, please comment when the link really fails, It is my duty to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got to making `eslint-disable` stricter is forcing to specify which rules should be disabled using [this eslint plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-abusive-eslint-disable.md)